# Jest testing with typescript and webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I use webpack for build typescript (ts-loader), react,...

my Webpack:

```
{
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                        before: [tsTransformAsyncToMobxFlow(/** options */)],
                    }),
                },
            }
```

I need this loader in Jest tests, but I dont know how set jest configuration file like this.

I know about ts-jest but I have to build exactly as webpack, bcs of  "tsTransformAsyncToMobxFlow", "web-workers", ...etc